# Show that A is a bounded operator in ℓ2 and ∥A∥2≤∑∞j=1∑∞i=1|aij|2

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I want to prove this:

Let $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left | a_{ij} \right |<\infty $ and $A: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is a linear transformation such that

$A(x)=y \Leftrightarrow  (a_{ij})(x_1,x_2,\cdots )^t=(y_1,y_2,...)^t$ whit $y_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}x_j$

Show that A is a bounded operator in $ \ell^2$ and  $   \left \| A \right \|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left | a_{ij} \right |^2$

I was able to prove that A is an operator but I don't see how to prove this $   \left \| A \right \|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left | a_{ij} \right |^2$

Comment: MathJax works in the title section, too, don't you know?

Comment: The inequality should fall out from your bounded operator proof.  If you don't see it, then probably you didn't *really* prove it's bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CS inequality for $y_i$, note that $y_i$ is given by the $\ell^2$-scalar product between $(a_{ij})_j$ and $x$. Then the claim follows almost immediately.